# Does PHP time() return a GMT/UTC Timestamp?

Tags: php

I just want to check if `time()` returns a UTC/GMT timestamp or do I need to use `date_default_timezone_set()`?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`time` returns a UNIX timestamp, which is timezone independent. Since a UNIX timestamp denotes the seconds since 1970 **UTC** you could say it's UTC, but it really has no timezone.

---

To be really clear, a UNIX timestamp is the same value all over the world at any given time. At the time of writing it's `1296096875` in Tokyo, London and New York. To convert this into a "human readable" time, you need to specify which timezone you want to display it in. `1296096875` in Tokyo is `2011-01-27 11:54:35`, in London it's `2011-01-27 02:54:35` and in New York it's `2011-01-26 21:54:35`.

In effect you're usually dealing with (a  mix of) these concepts when handling times:

- absolute points in time, which I like to refer to as *points in human history*
- local time, which I like to refer to as *wall clock time*
- complete timestamps in any format which express an absolute *point in human history*
- incomplete local wall clock time

Visualise time like this:

```
-------+-------------------+-------+--------+----------------+------>
       |                   |       |        |                |
Dinosaurs died        Jesus born  Y2K  Mars colonised       ???
```

<sub>*(not to scale)*</sub>

An *absolute point* on this line can be expressed as:

- 1296096875
- Jan. 27 2011 02:54:35 Europe/London

Both formats express the same absolute point in time in different notations. The former is a simple counter which started roughly here:

```
                          start of UNIX epoch
                                  |
-------+-------------------+------++--------+----------------+------>
       |                   |       |        |                |
Dinosaurs died        Jesus born  Y2K  Mars colonised       ???
```

The latter is a much more complicated but equally valid and expressive counter which started roughly here:

```
              start of Gregorian calendar
                           |
-------+-------------------+-------+--------+----------------+------>
       |                   |       |        |                |
Dinosaurs died        Jesus born  Y2K  Mars colonised       ???
```

UNIX timestamps are simple. They're a counter which started at one specific point in time and which keeps increasing by 1 every second (for the official definition of what a second is). Imagine someone in London started a stopwatch at midnight Jan 1st 1970, which is still running. That's more or less what a UNIX timestamp is. Everybody uses the same value of that one stopwatch.

Human readable wall clock time is more complicated, and it's even more complicated by the fact that it's abbreviated and parts of it omitted in daily use. *02:54:35* means almost nothing on the timeline pictured above. *Jan. 27 2011 02:54:35* is already a lot more specific, but could still mean a variety of different points on this line. *"When the clock struck 02:54:35 on Jan. 27 2011 **in London, Europe**"* is now finally an unambiguous absolute point on this line, because there's only one point in time at which this was true.

So, timezones are a "modifier" of "wall clock times" which are necessary to express a unique, absolute point in time using a calendar and hour/minute/second notation. Without a timezone a timestamp in such a format is ambiguous, because the clock struck 02:54:35 on Jan. 27 2011 in every country around the globe at different times.

A UNIX timestamp inherently does not have this problem.

---

To convert from a UNIX timestamp to a human readable wall clock time, you need to specify which timezone you'd like the time displayed in. To convert from wall clock time to a UNIX timestamp, you need to know which timezone that wall clock time is supposed to be in. You either have to include the timezone every single time with each such conversion, or you set the default timezone to be used with `date_default_timezone_set`.

Comment: Isn't what you say being in conflict with itself? "time returns a UNIX timestamp, which is timezone independent..." and then "It will be calculated based on the set timezone though, so if your timezone is set incorrectly, the timestamp will be off..." Cognitive dissonance.

Comment: The *format* of a UNIX timestamp is timezone independent. A UNIX timestamp expresses a unique, absolute point in human history. However, to arrive at this timestamp *from "wall clock time"* (e.g. "Jan. 26th 2011 21:54:35"), the timezone of this wall clock time needs to be taken into account. I admit this is expressed somewhat unclear.

Comment: I rewrote and clarified *a bit*. :)

Comment: Great writeup :) Although I think you could simply state that UNIX timestamp cannot have a timezone, because it is a number. It is not a date. It is a number of seconds. And number, cannot have any timezone. I think that's the whole point of timestamp.

Comment: @jayarjo Well, "dates" are also "just numbers". `2011-01-27 02:54:35` is just a bunch of numbers which collectively form a timestamp. The problem is what these numbers are relative to. `2011-01-27` is relative to a dude with long hair being born many moons ago. `02:54:35` is relative to the sun and the moon being visible in the sky, *which varies by location and therefore needs a timezone specifier*. `1296096875` is a number relative to an arbitrary fixed point in history, just like `2011-01-27`.

Comment: If what you say would be true, timestamp should vary depending of default timezone set... but it does not! Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079195/does-timestamp-should-change-when-default-timezone-differs), please.

Comment: @Flash No. The computer runs internally on UNIX time or something equivalent, it knows what the current absolute time is. It does not run on "human readable timezone dependent time". The timezone you set only affects what is printed when you request human readable time. If you ask it what the current absolute (UNIX) time is, it will always give you the same answer.

Comment: But when you set time in BIOS, you set hh:mm:ss, and not timestamp, so it has to depend of timezone somehow. The problem is that you may not know the timezone of operating system especially when working on some virtual machines (like Bit Web Server on Android).

Comment: @Flash That depends on your BIOS, I don't know what your BIOS does. Have you changed your BIOS's time to see whether that changes something? The fact is, PHP's `date_default_timezone_set` only affects what timezone a time is printed in when using `date()` (or related functions), it does not actually transport your computer into a different timezone. And even if it did, that would not change the current *absolute* (UNIX) time. All this of course depends on the system's time (and timezone) being set correctly.

Comment: Setting different timezone on Debian with tzselect and same datetime, makes timestamp different.

Comment: @Flash Of course, because you've changed your underlying OS's basic absolute time. If you tell your system that it's currently in Australia and it's currently 8am there, then it uses that information to figure out what current *absolute* time it is. And again, PHP's `date_default_timezone_set` **does not do the same thing**. As the function name implies, it sets the default timezone that is used when you print a time using the `date` function. It does not change your OS's time or PHP's understanding of time. It changes the format time is printed in for humans.

Comment: But absolute time (the system clock) is not absolute either. If it would be kept as unix timestamp, then people wouldn't worry so much about millenium bug. Ok... default_timezone_set does not affect it, but it should. As you never know what timezone you are in especially on virtual systems, that take time from system clock and then convert it to given timezone (that may be wrong).

Comment: @Flash No, the BIOS clock is not absolute either. See my answer in your other question for how the OS deals with that. The millennium bug had nothing at all to do with timezones. `date_default_timezone_set` *does* not and *should not* affect the actual time. Do you really want your PHP scripts to be changing the system's time every few seconds?! And yes, if your OS doesn't know the real absolute current time, PHP can't help you either. Note that the *timezone* of the OS doesn't need to be "correct", but its understanding of absolute time must be (again, see other answer).

Comment: So what do you mean by absolute time and how does OS know what it is?

Comment: @Flash Read everything I posted about the topic, here and in your other question. All the information is there, you just need to process and understand it. I know it's confusing, but I can't summarise it in a comment any better than I have already laid out.

Comment: Let me give you example, why you can't say that timestamp is timezone independent... when you overclock a computer, you sometimes overclock it too much and have to reset bios settings. Then, you set system clock in Y-m-d H:i:s format... It is only a time, set by you. When you are in Australia it will be different than in USA, at same time point. So computer doesn't really know what it is. It is timezone dependent. That's why I don't understand why eveyone keeps saying that timestamp is timezone undependent, when it is.

Comment: @Flash **A UNIX timestamp is timezone independent because a correct UNIX timestamp is the same everywhere across the world.** That's a fact. You cannot change it. That's the definition of a UNIX timestamp. You're confusing this issue with how a computer can correctly calculate a UNIX timestamp. As I have explained, that's the job of the OS, which uses the BIOS' time + its own timezone setting + possibly an NTP server to arrive at the correct time. If a UNIX timestamp of a system is not the same as another system, that system's time keeping is broken.

Comment: @Flash The fact that most computer's BIOSes keep time in HH:MM:SS without timezone information is a derelict of ancient computing hardware. Replace this worthless BIOS with one that keeps time as a UNIX timestamp. Does this now become clearer? The OS tries to compensate for the limited abilities of a BIOS to keep *absolute* time as best it can. EFI BIOSes for example offer much better time management: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Time_services

Comment: So it is a great problem, as many Android application use virtualized operating system inside them, and they have fixed timezone. For example [Bit Web Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb) has fixed timezone to `Asia/Jakarta`... so when writting timestamp to database, it has nothing to do with real time.

Comment: @Flash If the timestamp is written in "HH:MM:SS" format *without also storing timezone information*, then yes, that's quite worthless. As explained above, "HH:MM:SS" without timezone basically means nothing. Some databases support storing of timestamps + timezone (Postgres for example), which would solve that problem. Always storing Jakarta times may not even be incorrect though, you just need to know that the "HH:MM:SS" timestamp is represents a Jakarta time and treat it appropriately.

Comment: Didn't see a BIOS that let's you select timezone or to set time as timestamp... :/

Comment: @Flash You can always derive absolute time from local time and vice versa, as long as you have all the information you need. For local times you *need* to know the timezone, otherwise it's worthless.

Comment: To be honest I do understand all this, but wanted to warn people that they may have problems. I had to decompile that damn server to get that information, why timestamps are kept wrong. Would consider it as a bug, but think that people just don't care when creating apps for money.

Comment: @Flash So your one particular server's timekeeping was broken, not **timezone independent** UNIX timestamps as such.

Answer (score 16):

> Since PHP 5.1.0 (when the date/time functions were rewritten), every
>   call to a date/time function will generate a E_NOTICE if the timezone
>   isn't valid, and/or a E_WARNING message if using the system settings
>   or the TZ environment variable.

So in order to get a UTC timestamp you should check what the current timezone is and work off of that **or** just use:

```
$utc_str = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time());
$utc = strtotime($utc_str);
```

Comment: both time() and strtotime(gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time())) return the same result :-\

Comment: They *may* depending on how you set your timezone, but not always. See these for additional clarification: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Answer (score 5):

https://www.php.net/time

"Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)."

So I believe the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: I read over that GMT part a couple of times.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Answer (score 1):

One of the comments claimed: "both time() and strtotime(gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time())) return the same result"

Since I wasn't sure about that, I ran a test:

```
$now = strtotime(gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()));
$now2 = time();
echo ' now='.$now.' now2='.$now2.' diff='.($now - $now2);
```

Output was:

```
 now=1536824036 now2=1536806036 diff=18000
```

Diff is 18000 seconds = 5 hours = the timezone offset for the server running the test.