# PHP date_default_timezone_set() and time()

Tags: php, time

Does `date_default_timezone_set()` function affect the value of `time()`? Or does it just affect the `date()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time()` is timezone independent. See [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#100220) on PHP's time() documentation page:

> The function time() returns always timestamp that is timezone independent (=UTC).

Comment: thank you! I knew there must be an absolute value which is the basis of all other functions.

Comment: Just for other readers to get the timezone depenedent time: "when creating a UNIX timestamp your system needs to consider your local time and its timezone to come up with the correct timestamp." [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp)