# Different timezones have the same timestamp?

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone, utc

I ran this script:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get()."\n";
echo "----\n";

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kabul');
echo date_default_timezone_get()."\n";
echo "----\n";

echo time()."\n";
$dt = new DateTime;
echo $dt->format('U') . "\n";
echo "----\n";

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date_default_timezone_get()."\n";
echo "----\n";

echo time()."\n";
$dt = new DateTime;
echo $dt->format('U') . "\n";
```

and for all the 4 timestamp values, it says: `1325905766`.

I read somewhere that new DateTime always sets UTC as timezone, whatever the timezone setting, so I get that, but what about `time()`?

A few seconds before, on a different server (probably not in Europe (ideone.com)), it returns 4 times: `1325905723`.

That's the same! (A few seconds diff obviously, but the same timezone.)

`time()` always and only returns UTC??? What's going on??

Comment: I just ran into a similar problem not long ago. I was trying to set the timezone on a per-user basis (via a setting in the profile), but all it would change via the `date()` function was the timezone identifier at the end. It wasn't actually changing the *time* itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does PHP time() return a GMT/UTC Timestamp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they both use UTC.  Specifically, both `time()` and the `U` format return the number of non-leap seconds elapsed since midnight UTC on January 1, 1970 (the "Unix epoch").  As the epoch is a fixed point whose definition is independent of the user's timezone, and as the number of seconds since then is the same in all time zones (ignoring relativistic effects and whatnot), `time()` returns the same value regardless of time zone settings.

Comment: @Rudie: A second that's not a [leap second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Comment: Huh... So UTC is actually off by 34 seconds!? Weird. Didn't know about these mystery seconds that are created from nothing.

Answer (score 6):

[`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970 00:00:00 *GMT*.

The number of seconds elapsed since that particular point in time is the same whether you are in Asia/Kabul or Hither/Yon.