# Propel timestampable behavior in UTC

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, propel, utc

I am using Propel 1.6 with MySql. I set the timestampable behavior on all my tables as follows:

```xml
<database name="default" >
    <behavior name="timestampable">
        <parameter name="create_column" value="creation_date" />
        <parameter name="update_column" value="last_modified" />
    </behavior>

    <table name="book" phpName="Book">
        <!-- table colums omitted -->
    </table>
</database>
```

According to the [documentation](http://propelorm.org/behaviors/timestampable) of the Propel timestampable behavior, there is no parameter to specify the timezone.

I noticed that the timestampable behavior doesn't set the UTC time by default. For example, in my case, it sets UTC+1.

Doing a bit of investigation, I've seen that if I use the `preInsert()` hook to set the time instead of a behavior and I pass the Unix timestamp:

```php
public function preInsert(PropelPDO $con = null)
{
    $this->setCreationDate(time());
    return true;
}
```

the resulting time is still UTC+1. If I set the time using a `DateTime` object instead of a Unix timestamp:

```php
public function preInsert(PropelPDO $con = null)
{
    $this->setCreationDate(new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC')));
    return true;
}
```

I get the correct UTC time in the database.

I checked in the code and saw that the bahavior sets the time passing the Unix timestamp, hence resulting in UTC+1 on the database.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to configure the Propel timestampable behavior in UTC?
2. If it is not, where does Propel set the date format/time zone? Is using a `pre` hook and passing a `DateTime` object with the time zone specified the only way to get UTC time in the database (other than implementing a custom behavior)?
3. Also, if I can't configure the timezone of the Propel timestampable behavior, what's the whole purpose of it in a first place? (it is a pretty common practice to set UTC timestamps in a database)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't specifically mention timezone, but you should be able to set it doing something like this...

```
$objSourceTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$objDestinationTimezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

$objTime = new DateTime([some date], $objSourceTimezone);
$objTime->setTimeZone($objDestinationTimezone);

$objPropel->setTimestamp($time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

I'm using my local Pacific timezone (but you could use whatever you want) and converting it to a UTC format which is compatible with MySQL and Propel's `TIMESTAMP` column.

You can retrieve this data and display it in a different timezone by doing the opposite...

```
$objSourceTimezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$objDestinationTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');

$objTime = new DateTime($objPropel->getTimestamp(), $objSourceTimezone);
$objTime->setTimeZone($objDestinationTimezone);

print $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').”\n”;
```

Comment: Can you please clarify a few points... Where should the first block of code be executed? If it should be executed within a `preInsert()` hook, for example, this is similar to what I mentioned in my question and it is without using the timestampable behavior. And what is $objPropel? Is it an ActiveRecord model object?

Answer (score 0):

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp) and the [php documentation for `time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) it is clear that `time()` is supposed to return the seconds since the Unix epoch, which will always be in UTC. In fact, this is true in all of my projects which use Propel and the timestampable behavior. If your project is not doing so, there may be a deeper problem (that is, it's not an issue in Propel). That said, my answers to your questions are:

1. The behavior uses `time()` which is always in UTC per the PHP documentation.
2. See (1), and no, Propel has no such timezone setting (although [PHP does](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php), but it is not used for `time()`, but for `mktime()` instead). I think your `preInsert()` hook should work just fine as a workaround if you have to do that.
3. See (1), the timestampable behavior is super-simple, just uses `time()`, but you can always write your own! In fact, you can just copy the [existing behavior file](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/master/generator/lib/behavior/TimestampableBehavior.php) and then add it to your build properties ([Propel doc for custom behaviors](http://propelorm.org/cookbook/writing-behavior.html)).

Good luck!