# PHP timezone GMT conversion

Tags: php, timezone

In the database the time is stored in PHP `time()` format 
Timezone is `'America/New_York'`,

I would like to convert this data and to show the user the information on their timezone which will be in GMT(+/-).

Comment: `time()` has no timezone.

Comment: Ya, but the system knows the current timezone in which the time() is stored.

Comment: No, the value that `time` returns is a UNIX timestamp, which **has no timezone**. Not implicitly and not explicitly. It's **timezone independent.** See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4812178/476

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Datetime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateTimeZone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('@'.$row['datetime']);
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); 
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s);
```

Comment: It is not the error suppression operator here. The `@` symbol indicates a unix timestamp. Notice how it is in quotes. See [this blog post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/working-with-dates-and-times-in-php/) for more (under Getting Started).

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for the reply. The time stored in DB is of America/NewYork. I want to convert that to another timezone in GMT. Which will +5 or -5 like that.

The current data is stored in America/New_York

Comment: @AnishJoseph You will need to have an array that links timezone offsets to official timezones to do what you need to do. This code will work once you've done that.

Comment: @JohnConde You're exactly correct. I removed my comment to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @JohnConde Have you casted a VTC?