# Does timestamp should change when default timezone differs?

Tags: php

**Please understand, that this question wasn't answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp). Because if what they say in [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp) would be true, timestamp should vary depending of timezone on given hour.**

I got a problem with one project, because seems that timezone set on server was totally different then on machine where data is collected. Does timestamp change when default timezone changes in PHP? Should it or should it not?

```
php -r "date_default_timezone_set(\"Asia/Jakarta\");echo time();"
1397552668

php -r "echo time();"
1397552675
```

Seems it does not...am I right? Or am I doing something wrong?

Another test:

```
<?php
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo " : ".time();
echo "\n";
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo " : ".time();
echo "\n";
?>
```

Result:

```
Europe/Berlin : 1397553155
Asia/Jakarta : 1397553155
```

Comment: `date_default_timezone_get()` returns `Europe/Berlin`

Comment: A timestamp is always UTC, fetching the value of time() is unaffected by server time zone settings (or it SHOULD be, who knows where bugs can lurk).

Comment: Ok if timestamp is always UTC it should vary depending on timezone... because if timezone is not UTC, to make it UTC, it should be +/- some hours, or am I wrong?

Comment: I read it but it doesn't explain anything... because it seems to not to be true. As in example above. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @FlashThunder Apologies that I had misjudged this question until after reading deceze's answer. But I believe it only means that once you've actually passed it through a `date( 'd-m-Y H:i:s' )` the actual timezone difference is placed into context; where the UNIX timestamp is universal for all countries and timezones.

Comment: @MackieeE: So PHP gets system timezone instead of default timezone set in PHP when reading unix timestamp?

Comment: Can you clarify your logic why *"timestamp should vary depending of timezone on given hour."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem seems to be a wrong assumption of what `date_default_timezone_set` does. But first start with how computers keep time:

- the computer's BIOS typically keeps time, but is typically only set in date/hours/minutes without timezone information
- when the computer's OS boots, it uses the BIOS's time as a starting point
- the OS has a timezone setting, which tells it how to interpret the BIOS's time and figure out what the current *absolute* point in time is

  - note that some OSes interpret the BIOS's time as local time and others interpret the BIOS's time as UTC time; either way, BIOS time + OS timezone setting tells the OS what the current absolute time and the current local time is
- modern OSes will occasionally contact an internet time server via [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) to get an absolutely universally correct time; it may adjust the BIOS's clock based on this if it differs
- now that the OS has figured out what time it really is, it can give you the local time in any timezone you wish or the universal UNIX time

Now see [Does PHP time() return a GMT/UTC Timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp) for what the difference between "local" and "absolute" time is. Understanding that the OS deals with *absolute time* internally (likely in the form of a high-resolution UNIX timestamp) is critical. It does not keep time in the form of "HH:MM:SS", it only displays it as such *based on your set timezone* when it communicates times to you, a human.

What `date_default_timezone_set` does is simply choose the timezone in which human readable times are displayed. It does not change the OS's time or PHP's understanding of the current time or anything else. All it does is to tell PHP which timezone's local time to display when you do something like `date('H:i')`.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX timestamp is timezone independent so `time()` should always return same value. Other time manipulation functions (such as `Date` or `Datetime`) will depend on set timestamp, so if you do further manipulations with UNIX Timestamp, you will notice the difference.

Comment: That doesn't explain why in same hour timestamp doesnt vary on different timezones. Because when timezone is set to USA, and it is 8:00 am, it should be different than when timezone is set to Australia and hour is 8:00 am.

Comment: Unix time is number of seconds passed since 1970-01-01, so it is always same no matter what timezone you are in.

Comment: Yes it does: "UNIX timestamp is timezone independent" means that a particular instant in time, the Unix timestamp is the same wherever in the world you are (or tell PHP that you want to be).

Comment: You're trying to say that it takes timezone from system and not from php setting? It has to convert it to UTC somehow!

Comment: No, we are trying to say that it does not matter what is timezone, UNIX Time is always same. This is by design. You don't seem to understand it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: It does matter! Please read my first comment to this answer.

Comment: No it DOES NOT. In your first example there is 13seconds difference in time, due to the delay it took you to run the commands.

Comment: I do understand that it is UTC, but system clock is timezone dependent. So converting to UTC has to be done. 8AM in USA is not the same time as 8AM in Australia. BIOS doesn't keep timezone information. You set time, not timestamp there!

Comment: It is NOT UTC. It is TIMEZONE INDEPENDENT. The fact that it counts from 1970-01-01 in UTC, does NOT make it in UTC.

Comment: What does this have to do with BIOS? Different OS expects BIOS to have different time. Windows expects BIOS to be set to localtime while most linux expect UTC. This is not related to the question.

Comment: You don't understand me, farther discussion would be unproductive.

Comment: I suggest rereading everything in the comments and in posted duplicated question, because answers are here. Good luck.

Comment: I suggest you understanding what I am writting in comments and then decide. You say "timestamp is timezone idependent" and I don't agree, as when setting machine system time, you set it in some timezone, and it has to convert that time to timestamp. Conversion would be different depending of place where you are (a timezone!).

Comment: What makes you not agree? Even your own examples show that there is no difference as `time()` always give same results no matter what timezone you set. There is NO conversion going.

Comment: If i change system timezone, it is different. And hour is the same. So don't tell me it's not timezone dependent.

Comment: `time()` is not different. If you use `Date()` then yes, it makes it different. Still not relevat to what you have asked. And I also answered this in my answer. You seem to be going around the problem failing to grasp what is happening. I think I have tried enough. Good luck and bye.

Comment: Ok I'm lack of arguments. You don't even try to understand what am I asking about.