# PHP timestamps & timezone configuration

Tags: php, date, datetime

My plan:

- Get the current timestamp using `strtotime("now")`
- Convert that to timezone '0' - This is the part I don't know how to do. I have the number that represents the users timezone, like -8 hours for example.
- Store it in the database in timezone '0'
- Retrieve it from the database in timezone '0'
- Convert it to the users timezone in the opposite direction
- use the `date('', timestamp)` function to display it

How can I accomplish the conversion? Or am I going about this wrong?

I need to be able to store it in the database as a numerically represented time (like strtotime returns)

Comment: You can always get UTC time with gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: Cool. So I can store strtotime(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s')) and then when I retrieve just add the number of hours the user's timezone is offset by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `time()` is the same as `strtotime("now")` and you do not need to worry about converting the timezone of the timestamp, as the timestamp has no timezone:

[Does PHP time() return a GMT/UTC Timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp)

> `time` returns a UNIX timestamp, which is timezone independent. Since
>   a UNIX timestamp denotes the seconds since 1970 UTC you could say it's
>   UTC, but it really has no timezone.

You can then store that timestamp in your database. When you retrieve it you can convert it to the users timezone. With something like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$timestamp = '1429066967';
//Supported Timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
$userTimezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';

$dt = new DateTime();
// Set the timestamp
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);
// Set the timezone
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($userTimezone));
// Format the date
$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $date;
```

Outputs: **2015-04-14 20:02:47**

But if you only have the UTC offset you could try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$timestamp = '1429066967';
$offset = -8;
$userTimezone = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $offset*3600, false);


$dt = new DateTime();
// Set the timestamp
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);
// Set the timezone
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($userTimezone));
// Format the date
$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $date;
```

Which also outputs: **2015-04-14 20:02:47**

Comment: This only worked with negative offsets, ie: -5. Using a positive offset crashes the code.