# Wrong Timestamp/Timezone conversion

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, date, datetime

I have a DateTime from my MySQL Database which I convert to a Unix TimeStamp with Twig:

**In DB**: `2016-06-22 00:00:00`

**In Twig as TimeStamp**: `dbEntry.start|date('U')` ==> `1466546400`

**In Twig as Date** `dbEntry.start|date('Y-m-d H:i)` ==> `2016-06-22 00:00`

Doublechecking that timestamp here http://www.gaijin.at/olsutc.php says that the timestamp is local time.

I send this timestamp via AjaxCall to my Backend, where this happens:

```
$dateDB = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$date)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
dump($dateDB);
```

(`$date` being `1466546400`)

**Output**

`2016-06-21 22:00`

In all my `php.ini` files I set the timezone to `Europe/Berlin`, but the resulting timestamp is clearly `UTC`. Even setting the timezone manually with

```
$dateDB = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$date,new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    dump($dateDB);
```

leads to `2016-06-21 22:00` as well.

How does this happen, and where can I start to look for it, besides the `php.ini` files?

*Side Note*

I see that this has been addresses here [PHP timestamps & timezone configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639381/php-timestamps-timezone-configuration) as well, I could just manually add 7200 seconds, but would that still be correct in Winter due to DailightSavingTime?

Comment: I guess the timezone of the DB and your local timezone differ.

Comment: assuming that the date in the DB is correct, shouldn't you just set your default timezone to Europe/Berlin in php.ini? When you `format`, it uses your default timezone. It is still correct to create the DateTime object WITHOUT timezone.

Comment: As I said, all the `php.ini` files (cli & apache) have `Europe/Berlin` as the default timezone.

Comment: What does the Linux command: `date` show? And what distro are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that [createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is ignoring its third argument (time zone) by design:

> Note: The **timezone** parameter and the current timezone are ignored
>   when the **time** parameter either contains a UNIX timestamp (e.g.
>   946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

Here's a cleaner test case:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2016-06-22 00:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $dt->getTimestamp(), new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
var_dump($dt->format('c'), $dt2->format('c'));
```

```
string(25) "2016-06-22T00:00:00+02:00"
string(25) "2016-06-21T22:00:00+00:00"
```

Here, you'd need to change time zone afterwards (default time zone is only used when no time zone information exists):

```
$dt2->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
```