# PHP unix timestamp compare

Tags: php, time, unix-timestamp

I have an event date & time stored in my database that is being saved as a PHP unix timestamp. Im trying to check if today is greater than the event date and time.

The problem is - i'm trying to check it using local time (America/New_York), but im getting 2 different time zones. `time()` is displaying in EST and my database is displaying in UTC

Is there any way to check it correctly?

**My Event Date from database:**
1450447200 (December 18, 2015 2:00pm)

Im trying to compare it with php `time()`

am I maybe doing this wrong?

****UPDATE - ANSWER****

as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp#answer-11800739) I ended up doing this:

```
$utc_str = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time());
$today = strtotime($utc_str);

$event_datetime = $Event_timestamp;
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$utc_str_event = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", $event_datetime);
$event_date = strtotime($utc_str_event);
if($today >= $event_date){
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: `time` does *not* "display EST", unless your computer clock is completely screwed.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have wrong date on server(s). `time()` always should return epoch (epoch = UTC).

btw. saving date as int on database it isn't best practice

Comment: i'm well aware - my problem is that its being done with a plugin and I would rather not mess with the code.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this is correct but have you tried using `date_default_timezone_set`

Comment: `time()` is time zone independent