# Why is the difference between timestamp unix time and time() incorrect?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying do execute a php script with cron after 4 hours after saving an record in database. My problem here is not with cron, all here works fine(I'm sure of this because I'm receiving test mails from daemon cron every 4 hours as it should).

The problem is when I calculate the difference between the timestamp, converted to unix, and the current time and then execute some script.

But the diff bewtween these two times are adding 3 hours more to them and I don't know why but my script executes after 7 hours, instead of 4 hours. Can anyone help me please?

My code looks like this:

```php
<?php 
require_once('some-path/wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
   $constant= 4*3600;
   $table = 'notifications';
   $data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE status = 'pending'");
   $time = time();

foreach ($data as $r){
    $temp_data = strtotime($r->date_created);
    if ($time - $temp_data > $constant){
        $email = $r->email;
        $message = 'test';
        $subject = 'test';
        $headers = 'From: test <test@test.com>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $mail_client = wp_mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
        if($mail_client){
            $wpdb->update($tabel, array('status' => 'sent'), array('id_raport'=>$r->id_raport), array('%s'), array('%d'));
        }
    }
}
```

Example of date from database `Using strtotime(): 1458814621, Directly from database "2016-03-24 10:17:01"`

Now, I know I can do something like this to get the real localtime:

```php
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');
   $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
   $time = strtotime($date);
```

**Update.**
But this returns the same thing as the time() method.

Comment: Can you provide a few versions of the date_created that is returned by the database?

Comment: Is your time zone 3 hours from UTC?

Comment: @LiamSorsby, I've added at the ending of my question what you asked. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I think so, but only on winter time, on summer time I think is UTC+2. So how would my time() should look now?

Comment: @Anonymous by default the time() command will use your local time. take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php you will need to override the timezone default with date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");  or where ever you want

Comment: @LiamSorsby, if the time() returns the local time why it's not working, because the example of the time extracted from database when it was inserted was also the local time at that moment.

Comment: @Anonymous can you check to see if inserting a date into the database is definately localtime. I.e. insert a date and check to see if the datetime matches the expected time.

Comment: Yes, is the same time as the local time. So no problem here. @JoachimIsaksson, said something about UTC, but sometimes the UTC is + 2 hours, and sometimes + 3 hours, so I think by adding to the time(), time() + 3*3600 should work. But when the UTC is + 2 hours what should I do?

Comment: **Don't** add or subtract hours. Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateTimeZone`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) classes to properly handle the time. They know how to handle the DST too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now, I know I can do something like this to get the real localtime:
>
> ```
> date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');
> $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
> $time = strtotime($date);
> ```

A UNIX timestamp is not "local". A UNIX timestamp is the same all over the world. What you're doing in this code is merely converting a timestamp (`time()`) to a human readable format, and then reinterpreting it into a timestamp; the result is identical to the original `time()` value (or at least it should be!).

A human readable date/time format, such as you receive from MySQL (`2016-03-24 10:17:01`) is ***incomplete*** without a timezone. There are more than 24 different absolute points in time at which it is "2016-03-24 10:17:01" *somewhere* in the world. That timestamp by itself doesn't mean very much.
When you convert it into a UNIX timestamp using `strtotime`, it must take in additional information to convert such an ambiguous relative time format into an absolute point in time. That information comes from `date_default_timezone_set`, or whatever is set equivalently in your php.ini.

Your problem almost certainly just boils down to the timezone PHP assumes when doing `strtotime` not being the same timezone as what your MySQL datetime string is actually for. E.g., if your MySQL datetime expresses the time for UTC, but `strtotime` assumes Bucharest as the timezone to use, you'll see a difference of a few hours in the resulting absolute point in time.

Simply set/use the correct timezone in your PHP code; think about/be aware/decide on what timezone your MySQL dates are actually stored in.

Also see [Does PHP time() return a GMT/UTC Timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812178/476)

Comment: Yes, you are right, the time() and what I had are returning the exact same unix values.

Comment: Then what alternative do I have here?

Comment: What alternative do you need? 1) Figure out/decide/consider/meditate on what timezone your timestamps in MySQL are in. 2) Set that timezone using `date_default_timezone_set`. 3) Convert MySQL timestamps to correct UNIX timestamps using `strtotime`. – Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: 1. I already know what timezone MySQL has. It's UTC+2 (e.g. Europe/Bucharest). 2. I've already set that timezone. It's in my question. 3. I already use strtotime for converting to unix the dates from database. So what's the problem? Still not working as I want.

Comment: Then it comes down to some specific debugging... Get an official reference for what UNIX time it currently is (google it somewhere); check that PHP gives you the correct `time()`. If that fails, your server's clock may be screwed up. Next, take a specific date from your database and do the math what UNIX timestamp it should convert to; then check that PHP actually does this conversion correctly...

Comment: The time() value is the same with what I found on Google here http://www.unixtimestamp.com/. It works. My bad. Setting the date default timezone does the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) (a timestamp) is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. It is an absolute value.

The value you retrieve from the database (`2016-03-24 10:17:01`) is a relative value. It can represent different timestamps, depending on what time zone you use.

How to use the `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` classes:

```
 // Timestamp generated from PHP code
 // Current time
 $date1 = new DateTime();    // it uses the default timezone set in php.ini
                             // or by a previous call to date_default_timezone_set()
 // be more specific
 $date2 = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('US/Eastern'));
 // $date1 and $date2 represent the same moment in time ("now")
 echo(($date1 == $date2) ? 'Yes' : 'No');    // It displays "Yes"
 // Display them as timestamps
 echo($date1->format('U'));      // 1458816551
 echo($date2->format('U'));      // also 1458816551
 // Display $date1 as human-readable format:
 echo($date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e'));
 // It displays: 2016-03-24 12:49:11 Europe/Bucharest
 // Change $date1 to use the same timezone as $date2
 $date1->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('US/Eastern'));
 echo($date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e'));
 // Now it displays: 2016-03-24 06:49:11 US/Eastern

 // It provides easy ways to generate another date:
 $date3 = clone $date1;     // create a duplicate
 $date3->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));    // modify the duplicate
 // $date3 is 2 days in the future
 echo($date3->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e'));
 // It displays: 2016-03-26 06:49:11 US/Eastern

 // Get the difference between $date3 and $date1
 $diff = $date3->diff($date1)
 // you get the difference in date components (days, hours, minutes etc).
 print_r($diff);
```

---

A date-time value you extract from the database is incomplete. It lacks the timezone. If you stored the value in the database in the past then you should know what timezone it uses. If you get the datetime from the database using `SELECT NOW()` then the timezone is the default timezone used by the server. It is stored in the [`system_time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_system_time_zone) server variable and can be queried with `SELECT @@system_time_zone`

The query:

```
SELECT NOW() AS now, @@system_time_zone AS tz
```

returns the local date and time and the timezone used by the MySQL server.

You can use them to create a `DateTime` object to work with, as in the example code provided above.

As a general rule, always use a single time for the values you store as `datetime` in the database. I suggest using `UTC` because everything is relative to it and it doesn't observe [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). Or you can use columns of type `TIMESTAMP` instead (absolute timestamp do not care about timezones and DST) but they are more difficult to handle.