# Getting UTC time in php Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, time, laravel-5.3

In my `config/app.php` timezone is `UTC` and `time()` is used to get the current time stamp

So is it the correct way to get UTC time in Laravel??

Comment: it's already set as UTC

Comment: Then that should work just fine. You could also use [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)

Comment: Thanks. One more simple question.Is there any laravel package available for getting user timezone?

Comment: @GeethuJojo You need to have the user specify their preferred timezone. You could also infer it via the client IP but that would annoy people who use a proxy or VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

You can get more format here

[PHP: date - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: But I need  UTC timestamp

Comment: Time returns a UNIX timestamp, which is timezone independent. Since a UNIX timestamp denotes the seconds since 1970 UTC you could say it's UTC, but it really has no timezone.
[Look this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp)