# unix timestamp datetime difference php

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I am running into a strange problem with a discrepancy between a unix timestamp and the converted result.

Here is an example:

```
$timestamp = 1489132800;  

echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $timestamp);

// echo statement =  Friday 10th of March 2017 03:00:00 AM

// on unixtimestamp.com  this equates to 03/10/2017 @ 8:00am (UTC)
```

Does anyone have any idea why there would be a 5 hour difference?  Does the date function rely on some internal time setting?

Comment: Hello @AaronBucky! Both are giving same results. https://eval.in/751872. Please check this article for more detail : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

This is because your converter returns the time in UTC, while your local timezone is 5 hours behind UTC.

You can check your current timezone via date_default_timezone_get() and change it with date_default_timezone_set().

You can also check with some onlineconverters that return your local time as well as UTC time: http://www.convertunixdate.com/