# Changing the time zone in PHP is not working

Tags: php, timezone

My hosting company set the default time zone in my php.ini to America/Chicago. I confirmed the time zone by checking `phpinfo()` and echoing `date_default_timezone_get()` in my PHP code.

However, I tested changing the time zone in my PHP code but had no luck.

Firstly, I tested:

```php
echo (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
echo '<br>';
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
```

And the two echoed timestamps were the same.

Then, I tested:

```php
echo (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
echo '<br>';
$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $now->getTimestamp();
```

And the two echoed timestamps were still the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getTimestamp` returns a [UNIX Epoch timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). UNIX timestamps are always the same all over the world. Time zones only affect human readable time, e.g. when you do `$now->format('H:i:s')`.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812178/476 for more explanation.

Comment: You seems to be correct but it does not help solving his problem

Comment: In what way doesn’t it? It solves the problem in that it clears up a wrong expectation. The code works fine as is, the expectation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

use `date_default_timezone_set("UTC")`

```
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
 echo date_default_timezone_get().date('Y-m-d h:I:s');
?>
```

[ExampleDemo](https://paiza.io/projects/Gb-ObYOcqShFKe1MvQFJIw)

Answer (score -1):

Check this way if you able to set the time zone or not.

```
 date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
 echo date_default_timezone_get();
 echo date(“Y-m-d h:I:s”);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204838/discussion-on-answer-by-amit-sharma-changing-the-time-zone-in-php-is-not-working).