# Regarding the time.time() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, python-3.7, epoch

Edit -: I have made a slight mistake when posting the question and please go to the bottom where I have mentioned the mistake I have made if you come across this question.

I am a beginner in Python and trying to grasp the following concept on time module.

Following is what I did,

[image: My code on idle (image)]

Here, between the two calls of `time.time()` , I changed the system clock. However, as the image shows, time.time() has been able to calculate the seconds since the epoch correctly regardless of the changes of the system clock. Does this mean that the system clock does not affect the time.time() function?

However, the documentation for the time.time() function tells the following,

> While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can
> return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been
> set back between the two calls.

link to the documentation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

So I am wondering how come my system clock changes have not affected the calculations?

I am a beginner to programming and would be glad if someone could help me understand what is going on here.

Thanks.

## This is a re-edit

I have made a mistake by not mentioning how I changed the system time. I changed the system time by changing the time zone and thankfully,  Aplet123 has pointed this out to me in the comments.

Comment: Changing the timezone will not affect `time.time`.

Comment: How exactly have you changed what in your system clock?

Comment: I made the change by changing the time zone. @Aplet123 thankfully mentioned that changing the timezone does not affect time.time. Could you kindly let me know why it does not affect? (I am struggling to understand these concepts. Thanks in advance.)

Comment: Well, it does not affect what time it is. It just displays the time as if you're in a different country. That's still _now_, you haven't transported into the future.

Comment: @Aplet123 [UNIX epoch time is *not* UTC.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812178/476)

Answer (score 2):

For accessing the system time use the datetime module.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(time)
```

1. Here you will see it imports datetime from the datetime module.
2. The variable 'now' to the current system time.
3. The 'time' variable is assigned the system time (taken from the 'now' variable) formatted as HH:MM:SS.
4. This is printed to the screen.

Changing the system time **WILL** change the time displayed here.

For information on how to change how the time is displayed and including the date, see the datetime documentation linked below.

[datetime Module Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)