# How to print the UTC UNIX Epoch/timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

When I print the unix epoch, with something like `time.time()` it seems to print the timestamp in my local timezone. Especially from what converters like: https://www.epochconverter.com tell me.

Does anyone know how I can print the UNIX Epoch/timestamp but actually in UTC time? Thank you so much.

Comment: There is no such thing as a timezone for UNIX timestamps. You’ll need to be more detailed here about what you’re getting and why you think it’s wrong.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()` should do the job.

Comment: @Deepak That should be no different from `datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()` or `time.time()`.

Comment: @deceze I do get different responses for `datetime.now()` vs `datetime.utcnow()` corresponding to my local time vs UTC. Accordingly, the seconds elapsed has a difference of 19800s (+5:30 for my time zone) for me.

Comment: @Deepak Ah, yes, when taking the `timestamp` of a `utcnow`, it’ll probably use your local timezone for conversion, so that result is actually *wrong*.

Comment: @deceze but that is what I need.

Comment: Hey thanks @DeepakGouda :) it seems to work.

Comment: For the record, I think you don’t really understand what you need…

Comment: When you go to that website linked in your question, it tells you “The current Unix epoch time is ...”. `time.time()` should give you *that* timestamp. That’s the correct UNIX time. There’s no such thing as “local” or “UTC” UNIX time.

Comment: @deceze I am making a discord bot with the discord.py Python wrapper, and I am trying to calculate ping in MS. And I can print when the user's message was created in a UNIX timestamp which is measured in UTC.

Comment: May I interest you in this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4812170/476

Comment: @Deepak I implore you to read my [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67121498/476).

Comment: @deceze Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "UTC UNIX Epoch time". There's UNIX Epoch time, period. It's the same all over the world. It is timezone independent. As long as your computer's clock is set correctly, `time.time()` will give you the correct UNIX epoch time. `datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()` will give you the same UNIX Epoch time. You don't need to convert anything and there's nothing to convert.

Now, to address [the comment by Deepak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67113575/how-to-print-the-utc-unix-epoch-timestamp#comment118629395_67113575), which I think is important:

> I do get different responses for `datetime.now()` vs `datetime.utcnow()` corresponding to my local time vs UTC. Accordingly, the seconds elapsed has a difference of 19800s (+5:30 for my time zone) for me.

**This is a known pitfall with `datetime.utcnow` and is in fact [addressed in the manual](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow):**

> **Warning:** Because naive `datetime` objects are treated by many `datetime` methods as local times, it is preferred to use aware datetimes to represent times in UTC. As such, the recommended way to create an object representing the current time in UTC is by calling `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

To unpack this a bit:

When you call `datetime.now()`, it returns you a *naïve* `datetime` object (meaning it has no `tzinfo` timezone attached) for your current local time:

```
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 16, 9, 50, 3, 571235)
```

The time represents my current wall clock time, but it does not know what timezone it's in. So this timestamp could really represent about two dozen different absolute timestamps on this planet, depending on what timezone you take it as.

When using this object's `timestamp()` method to convert it to an **absolute** UNIX timestamp, *some* timezone must be assumed. Python will assume your computer's local timezone for the conversion. Which is fine for `datetime.now()`, because this timestamp was created with my local time anyway:

```
>>> datetime.now().timestamp()
1618559403.571235
```

This is the correct UNIX timestamp at the time of writing. Not *"for my local timezone"*, but **globally**. At the time of writing, it's `1618559403` everywhere in the world.

Now, if you use `datetime.utcnow()`, it will give you a *naïve* timestamp for the current UTC time:

```
>>> datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 16, 7, 50, 3, 571235)
```

Note how it's off by 2 hours from the previous `datetime.now()`, which is fine, because that's the current local time in the UTC timezone. But since this timestamp is still naïve, when converting it to a UNIX timestamp, Python must assume *some* timezone, and will assume my local timezone. So it's giving me the UNIX timestamp for 7:50:03 *of my local time*:

```
>>> datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
1618552203.571235
```

**Which is not the current UNIX time.** It's off by two hours. It's the UNIX time of two hours ago.

If we'd do this properly, by creating an *aware* timestamp and taking its UNIX time, we'd get the correct UNIX time:

```
>>> datetime.now(timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 16, 7, 50, 3, 571235, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp()
1618559403.571235
```

Note how the human readable time is the same as we got for `datetime.utcnow()`, but the UNIX timestamp is *correctly* the one we got for `datetime.now().timestamp()`. Which is also the same as we'd get for `time.time()`:

```
>>> from time import time
>>> time()
1618559403.571235
```

When pasting this into https://www.epochconverter.com, which you reference:

> GMT: Friday, 16 April 2021 07:50:03.571
> Your time zone: Friday, 16 April 2021 09:50:03.571 GMT+02:00 DST

Which is correct. In UTC/GMT, this UNIX timestamp represents 7:50am, and in my local timezone it's 9:50am.

If we take the incorrect naïve `datetime.utcnow()` timestamp `1618552203.571235`, the result is:

> GMT: Friday, 16 April 2021 05:50:03.571
> Your time zone: Friday, 16 April 2021 07:50:03.571 GMT+02:00 DST

Which is incorrect. That was 2 hours ago, not now.

Comment: I needed the timestamp like if I was located in a UTC timezoned country? Is it that hard to understand? I know that, that isn't really the correct UNIX time.

Comment: It doesn't matter *where* you are located! UNIX time is the same all over the world. Is *that* so hard to understand? — If `time.time()` doesn't give you what you need, then either your computer's clock is wrong, or whatever you're comparing it to is wrong. You would need to provide some concrete values here if you need a concrete answer, without knowing the exact values you're working with or what you expect them to be, I can't say much more about this than that there is no such thing as a UTC UNIX timestamp.

Comment: You're just misunderstanding. I and I do get what you mean. I already got the help I needed, so just please stop.

Comment: Fine. It's not just about you though, this is for future reference for anyone coming across this. Whatever you do with this information is up to you, whether your code is correct or not, it's your code…