# How to convert timestamp to time in different zones in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have an existing data coming from a third party which has `timeStamp` column generated using `time.time()`. How to convert that column into local times? I want to add two more columns "NYK_Time" and " LONDON_Time"

```
import time
import pandas as pd

timeStamp = time.time()
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['number', 'timeStamp'])
for t in range(4):
    df.at[t, 'number'] = t
    df.at[t, 'timeStamp'] = time.time()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: In order to convert, I believe you would need to know the timezone that `timeStamp` originally came from...

Comment: @John UNIX timestamps don’t have a timezone and are universally the same. You don’t need to know where it came from.

Comment: @deceze but when i convert it will will give different time for different regions beacuse initial time set is in UTC

Comment: Wat? Please show what you’re doing, what the outcome is, what you expected instead.

Comment: @deceze I understand that unix timestamps don't have time zones.  But the questioner wants to convert a timestamp into "local times" in two different time zones.  Surely the original source time zone would be needed?

Comment: You can convert a UNIX timestamp to a local time when you know the local timezone you want to convert it to. End of story. You don't need to know the "origin timezone", because a UNIX timestamp is timezone independent…!? If you need a longer explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812178/476

Answer (score -1):

```
timeStamp = time.time()
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['number', 'timeStamp'])
for t in range(4):
    df.at[t, 'number'] = t
    df.at[t, 'timeStamp'] = time.time()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I would convert timeStamp into another variable

```
timestamp_australia = timeStamp.tz_localize(tz='Australia/Brisbane')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['number', 'timeStamp', 'Australia'])
for t in range(4):
    df.at[t, 'number'] = t
    df.at[t, 'timeStamp'] = time.time()
    df.at[t, 'Australia'] = timestamp_australia
    time.sleep(1)
```